# Angular: ternary operator in ngFor throw error Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, ternary-operator

I have in my code a ngFor loop in a div that looks like that:

```
  <div formArrayName="i===0 ? 'viaOut' : 'viaIn' " fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" *ngIf="viaOut">
        <div *ngFor="i===0 ? 'let via of newRequest.controls.roundway.controls[i].controls.viaOut.controls; let j=index' : 'let via of newRequest.controls.roundway.controls[i].controls.viaIn.controls; let j=index' ">
```

Before using the ternary operator, I only had a simple ngFor and a normal formArrayName, it worked perfectly, but when I changed to this it stopped working and I get in my browser console the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("me="i===0 ? 'viaOut' : 'viaIn' " fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" *ngIf="viaOut">
            <div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="i===0 ? 'let via of newRequest.controls.roundway.controls[i].controls.viaOut.controls; let j="): ng:///AppModule/NouvelledemandeComponent.html@132:17
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".
```

Also, I already import BrowserModule (and it works well as everything worked before I used ternary operator)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign strings or code to `*ngFor` loop, although it seems like a for-loop, it really just takes takes an [NgIterable](https://angular.io/api/core/NgIterable), anything iterable like an array, not code. So you can't use ternary operator.

For instance, if you feed it an array, it will work

```
let a of list
```

When you add even just parenthesis, it'll break

```
(let a of list)
```

Comment: I removed the simple quotes and this error disapperared but now I get another one:
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("me="i===0 ? 'viaOut' : 'viaIn' " fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" *ngIf="viaOut">
            <div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="i===0 ? let via of newRequest.controls.roundway.controls[i].controls.viaOut.controls; let j=i"):

Comment: Aww really, that's too bad I can't use it, I will have to find another way to proceed and right now I have no idea how to do.
Well whatever thank you for your answer